# Adding Custom price with woocomerce product price in Cart & Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom field in the woocommerce which has extra price of frames for pictures, now if picture price is 10$ and user selects a frame it will add up 5$ let say and total will be 15$.

Now if i add another product it's selected custom frame price should get added.
e.g **Product 1** price is: 10$ and the frame slected on it is:**frame1** whos price is 5$ so total will be 15$ for that product and if **Product 2** is added with price 10$ and selected **frame2** with its price is 6$ total of that product will be 16$ however **grandtotal** will be 31$

The solution which is near to what i'm trying to do is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'calculate_discounted_price', 10, 2 );

// Display the line total price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'display_discounted_price', 10, 2 );

function calculate_discounted_price( $price, $values ) 
{

    $price += $_SESSION['framed_price'];
    return $price;

}
    }
```

I'm storing the frame value in session and it gets updated every time user click on the frame i'm using ajax on that and till that everything is working fine. i'm getting values as well.
This function is basically iterating over the added products and adding the last frame price to every product in the cart.
How do we add the product price with it's custom frame price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to this, that's solve the issue:

```
// Change the line total price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'calculate_discounted_price', 10, 2 );
// Display the line total price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'display_discounted_price', 10, 2 );

function calculate_discounted_price( $price, $values ) {
    // You have all your data on $values;
    $price += 10;
    return $price;
}

// wc_price => format the price with your own currency
function display_discounted_price( $values, $item ) {
    return wc_price( $item[ 'line_total' ] );
}
```

Reference: [woocommerce, how can i add additional cost in cart product total price?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134637/woocommerce-how-can-i-add-additional-cost-in-cart-product-total-price)

Comment: This code works great for setting a custom price - I am noticing that while the product subtotal and cart grand total are correct, the cart subtotal still displays the default price. Can that also be updated to avoid confusion?

Comment: hey @LouisW sorry i left working on wordpress from long time, and i remember there was some issue i sorted it out later